# Vulkan Push Constants never assigned or updated

Tags: c++, vulkan

I have been reading through Sascha Willem's example on push constants [here](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan/blob/b9f0ac91d2adccc3055a904d3a8f6553b10ff6cd/examples/pushconstants/pushconstants.cpp) and have attempted to implement them myself.

<s>Oddly the `VkPhysicalDeviceProperties.limits.maxPushConstantsSize` is `1437341456` bytes which makes me think something else is very wrong.</s> After rechecking it is showing as a more realistic value of `256` (I assume I did something incorrectly previously)

In my test project I have uniform buffers working, and I then started to tinker with push constants which will hopefully explain the inbetween state of my vertex shader

Here are some details of what I implemented:
From what I understand, on creating a pipeline layout I need to specify the push constant ranges, which I do like so:

```
VkPushConstantRange pushConstantRange {};
pushConstantRange.stageFlags = VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT;
pushConstantRange.offset = 0;
pushConstantRange.size = sizeof(ObjectPushConstantData);
```

And I add the push constant ranges to the pipeline layout CI like so:

```
pipelineLayoutInfo.pushConstantRangeCount = 1;
pipelineLayoutInfo.pPushConstantRanges = &pushConstantRange;
```

When creating my command buffers, I'm calling `vkCmdPushConstants` before drawing like so:

```
vkCmdPushConstants(this->commandBuffers[i], this->pipelineLayout, VK_SHADER_STAGE_VERTEX_BIT, 0, static_cast<uint32_t>(sizeof(ObjectPushConstantData)), &testObject);
vkCmdDrawIndexed(this->commandBuffers[i], static_cast<uint32_t>(indices.size()), 1, 0, 0, 0);
```

The type `ObjectPushConstantData` looks like so:

```
struct ObjectPushConstantData {
    glm::vec3 position;
    glm::vec3 rotation;
};
```

My vertex shader looks like this:

```
#version 450
#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable

layout(binding = 0) uniform UniformBufferObject {
    mat4 model;
    mat4 view;
    mat4 proj;
} ubo;

layout(location = 0) in vec3 inPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 inColor;

layout(push_constant) uniform PushConsts {
    vec3 position;
    vec3 rotation;
} pushConsts;

layout(location = 0) out vec3 fragColor;

void main() {
    gl_Position = ubo.proj * ubo.view * ubo.model * vec4(pushConsts.position, 1.0);
    fragColor = inColor;
}
```

Comment: Do you recreate command buffers per frame? Or do you only create them once? And I'm not sure about the usage of `vec3` there might be alginment issues, try to use `vec4` and `gl::vec4` instead.

Comment: In this case I create them when recreating the swapchain due to resize etc

Comment: I have also tried vec4, with no success, I believe the alignment is 4bytes in push constants

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think you need to recreate them every frame, because the push constant data will be copied into the command buffer immediately (it doesn't store pointer but copies the actual data). That's at least how I understand them.

Comment: In the example I am following that's not the case, and in my mind would somewhat offset the performance benefit of using them over UBOs in the first place

Comment: The example states: "The sample uses these to push different **static parameters** for rendering multiple objects". So I guess they are not meant to change between frames. In practice they should be faster then UBOs and are more flexible. And at some point you probably need to re-record commandbuffers per frame anyway.

Comment: The entire point of push constants is to push data per frame to a command buffer, they are *constant* from the perspective of the shader. Even if they couldn't change per frame, I would expect *something* to render.

Comment: As already noted, push constants are part of the command buffer state, so they are valid as long as the command buffer using them is valid. So this is use-case is perfectly fine. Why this doesn't work is hard to tell, maybe an object went out of scope. A first start would be to run your code through RenderDoc and see if the push constants are what you passed via the command buffer.

Comment: They are indeed appearing as I set them, provided I did the correct thing in renderdoc. (went to the vertex shader, found the pushConsts under UniformBuffers and hit Go)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a look at your shader, this does not seem to be a problem related to the push constants, but rather the lack of taking the actual vertex position into account.

In this line:

```
gl_Position = ubo.proj * ubo.view * ubo.model * vec4(pushConsts.position, 1.0);
```

You only multiply the push constant position, which is uniform for all shader invocations.

It seems you forgot to include the actual vertex position, to which you'd typically just add your uniform push constant position like this:

```
gl_Position = ubo.proj * ubo.view * ubo.model * vec4(inPosition + pushConsts.position, 1.0);
```

Comment: Wow I'm staggered that I didn't notice that! Many thanks for your help